# All the sudden my links not working in php

Tags: php, css, hyperlink

I have a page where all links where working properly but all the sudden some links are not working anymore.

I am puzzling myself to undersand why. Nothing really changed. Maybe some css details.

Is there anyone who can give a clue?

Thank you for any help. me abou twhat might have happened.
Francesco

PS sorry forgot to say that looking at the source code the links are there and they work. In design view they just do nothing. They look like normal text.

```
<div id="centrale"><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;Upcoming events</h1>
    <div class="centrale_event"><a href="events.php" class="new">CLICK HERE TO SEE ALL UPCOMING EVENTS</a></div>
    <p class="line">&nbsp;</p>
    <?php do { ?>
 <div class="centrale_event">
    <p><img src="<?php echo 'drawings/'.$row_rstevents['event_picture']; ?>" class="float" alt="" /><span class="big"><?php echo $row_rstevents['event_title']; ?></span></p>
    <p><strong><em>Starting on <?php echo $row_rstevents['date']; ?></em></strong></p>
    <p><strong>Where</strong>:&nbsp;<?php echo $row_rstevents['event_town']; ?></p>
    <p><strong>Place</strong>: <?php echo $row_rstevents['place']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo extractFirst($row_rstevents['event_details']); ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="events_details.php?event_ID=<?php echo $row_rstevents['event_ID']; ?>" class="new">MORE INFO HERE</a></p> 
    <p class="line">&nbsp;</p>
 </div>
  <?php } while ($row_rstevents = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstevents)); ?>

  <div class="centrale_event"><p><a href="events.php" class="new">CLICK HERE TO SEE ALL UPCOMING EVENTS</a></p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: in what manner are they not working? are they not clickable? do they take you to the wrong place? do they not look the way they used to? they might be missing a `href`... there might be another, invisible, `div` on top of them. please post your generated html (view source in browser)

Comment: can you provide some code samples/exceptions whatever .. people around here are no mind readers ..

Comment: Added a PS abovee please see there. hope this helps

Comment: @francesco: I am sorry, but the update really does not help (much). Exactly how does the rendered HTML look? What is "design view"?

Comment: When looking at the webpage all seem ok but some links (related to details coming from database) do nothing. With the mouse over they seem normal text. No link.

If I go to the source code the links are there and working.

I am sorry I don't what else to say to explain this. It seems so strange to me.

Comment: You mentioned PHP in the title but not in your details...s your system setup correctly for local testing?

Comment: What is "design view"? Is this a case of "Dreamweaver can't cope with my code?"

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Dreamweaver? I thought you might seeing as you mentioned Design View.. If that's the case then just hit F12 to view in a browser, the design view of DW is pretty lame.

Comment: Yes I am using Dreaweaver and I can see the page in a browser. And that is what is happening. I might have an error somewhere but checked and found noting.

Comment: Well can you copy and paste the code that is causing the issues? Either from Dreamweaver itself or from the source code (ctrl+u in FF/Chrome View>Source in IE)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with the link problem, but is there a reason you're using a `do {} while ()` loop to output your database results? Using this construct will output at least one blank event before any actual data shows up, as the first time around the loop, you haven't retrieved any data from the query yet. Any reason you can't do a regular `while() { }` loop?